# Drawing texture on lines with three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying NPR with three.js. I'm new with computer graphics. I want to extrude the lines segments and put textures on it. Is it possible to put texture after extruding the line segments using ExtrudeGeometry or should I first triangulate the lines, and then put texture on it?

Thanks in advance.